# sending an email from excel which attachs rows from a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a vba code which sends an email with an attachment.  I now need to change this so that it will attach rows from a different worksheet in the workbook.  VBA below:

```
Sub Fuel_LevelW03()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please order fuel as attached." & vbNewLine & _
              "" & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & _
              ""

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Fuel Order Glen Eden W03"
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add ("H:\Fuel Order Sheets\Glen Eden W03 Pump Station.xlsx")
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Change event code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("M4:M733"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 1000 Then
            Call Fuel_LevelW03
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: please describe more about what you're trying to accomplish? Do you want to create a new attachment file containing only a few rows of data? Or do you want to include a table of data in-line in the email?

Comment: I want to create a new attachment file, which will come from a worksheet within the work book.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You need to open the sheet you want and copy data to a new workbook, then attach it to an email.

Comment: I've got a vba for it to send automatically once a value reaches a certain level.  The code looks for a different spreasheet located in another drive.  I want to add a worksheet with the information on the spreadsheet and have that worksheet sent as an attachment with the automatically created email

Comment: pls show the code you are currently working with...

Comment: @user3186437 Lol. You can edit your question instead of add the code inside the comment.

Comment: @david Zemens are you able to see the code in the question?

Comment: Yes, I can, but you mention that you have code which sends automatically once a value reaches a threshold level, but you don't provide that code above.  That was the code I was asking about. In any case, it looks like there may be an answer for you already.

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks I've added the change event code to my original questions, i hope you can read it and i've done it properly.  I need to get away from directing the attachment to a drive as this is not going to be available any more. The workbook i have has 7 sheets and each sheet has a change event code

Comment: The previous answer seems correct: you need to save the file *somewhere* before you can attach it to an email. You can do this temporarily, and kill/delete the file when the macro is finished, using the `Kill path$` command.

Comment: sorry i'm a bit confused.  Which file do i need to save?  The original workbook or the information i need to attach in the email?  Can i not just attach a worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right. First of all you need to copy your sheet to another workbook, then you need to save it. Finally you can send the email with this infromation.

Example:

```
Const MY_SHEET_NAME As String = "BD"
Const BD_PATH As String = "c:\myLocation\"

Sub doAll()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, strbody As String
    Dim path As String

    ' Create a file
    Sheets(MY_SHEET_NAME).Activate
    Sheets(MY_SHEET_NAME).Copy

    path = BD_PATH & "report" & Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    ' Send e-mail
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please order fuel as attached." & vbNewLine & _
              "" & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & _
              ""

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "email address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .subject = "Fuel Order Glen Eden W03"
        .body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add ("H:\Fuel Order Sheets\Glen Eden W03 Pump Station.xlsx")
        .Attachments.Add (path) '<--- Adding new sheet.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I probably haven't worded my question properly  I can't have the attachment looking at a drive as there are no shared drives to save the spreadsheet. Can i add a new sheet with the info that was in H:\ and direct the attachments to the worksheet instead of the drive?

Comment: You need to save your file somewhere before attach it in email. So you can save your file in C:, H: and so on.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it not possible just to change the add attacment to attach a worksheet?  I probably haven't worded my question properly.  I have 7 worksheets in the workbook each with their own change event followed by a module for each sheet.  Instead of the attachment going to H:\etc, i'd just like it to attach from a new worksheet (number8 ) in that workbook

Comment: I don't think so. You need to attach a saved workbook. If you don't save and try to email the file, Office just save it in temp folder then attach the file.